# How to put catche in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

Earlier we are putting catche in liferay with help of below code.

```
 MultiVMKeyPoolUtil.put("SCHOOL", "ID", "Files");
```

In Liferay 6.2 MultiVMKeyPoolUtil not available so how can we put catche.
 There are no method like put in MultiVMPoolUtil class. I had search many alternative but couldn't find put method in it.

Comment: Did you try with this util: FinderCacheUtil?

Comment: Actually, if you would try and tell us what you want to achieve, it could be a lot easier to help you out here ;)

Comment: Thanks for comment I had put solution as answer which work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MultiVMKeyPoolUtil not supported by liferay 6.2. I had used MultiVMPoolUtil class like below.

```
MultiVMPoolUtil.getCache("SCHOOL").put("ID","Files");
```

If you want to put collection as cache use below code.We require to make list serializable

```
MultiVMPoolUtil.getCache("SCHOOL").put("ID",(Serializable) courses);
```